# Import list of dates from csv and export record with latest date only

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

For some reason my code is not pulling the latest date for this csv file. With other csv files it is working. The csv files it's working for also have multiple values, and some $null values for the date.

```
Function GetLatestLogonUserFromFile
{
    Param ($csvInputFile)

    $csvInputWithLatestLogonUser = @()
    $csvInput = Import-Csv $csvInputFile
    $SamAccountName = $csvInput[0].SamAccountName

    Write-Host "Finding real last logon for $SamAccountName..."
    ForEach ($userInfo in $csvInput)
    {
        If (($userInfo.LastLogon -gt $csvInputWithLatestLogonUserLastPlaceholder.LastLogon) -and ($userInfo.LastLogon))
        {
            $csvInputWithLatestLogonUser = $userInfo
        }
        If ($userInfo.LastLogon)
        {
            $csvInputWithLatestLogonUserLastPlaceholder = $userInfo
        }
    }

    If ($csvInputWithLatestLogonUser)
    {
        $LastLogon = $csvInputWithLatestLogonUser[0].LastLogon
        Write-Host 'LastLogon =' $LastLogon
        $tableResults = $csvInputWithLatestLogonUser
    } Else {

        Write-Host "no LastLogon found"
        $tableResults = $csvInput[0]
    }

    $tableResults | Export-Csv 'C:\Scripts\Tests\TestResults.csv'
}

GetLatestLogonUserFromFile 'C:\Scripts\Tests\RealLastLogon_Test.csv'
```

Csv File...

```
"Domain Name","Domain Controller","SamAccountName","LastLogon"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM01.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/9/2016 6:00 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM02.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/4/2016 6:44 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM03.example.net","FAHS92FA","12/24/2015 11:42 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM04.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/5/2016 7:01 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM05.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/9/2016 7:08 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM06.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/11/2016 6:55 PM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM07.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/3/2016 8:28 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM08.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/12/2016 8:31 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM09.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/4/2016 5:53 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM10.example.net","FAHS92FA","1/22/2016 8:30 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM11.example.net","FAHS92FA","1/13/2016 1:06 PM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM12.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/9/2016 12:04 PM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM13.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/11/2016 11:24 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM14.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/12/2016 6:32 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM15.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/11/2016 6:56 PM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM16.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/11/2016 9:08 PM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM17.example.net","FAHS92FA","12/18/2015 2:18 PM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM18.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/12/2016 8:06 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM19.example.net","FAHS92FA","12/22/2015 8:38 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM20.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/9/2016 1:15 PM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM21.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/9/2016 7:21 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM22.example.net","FAHS92FA","1/28/2016 6:32 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM23.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/9/2016 1:44 PM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM24.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/12/2016 8:35 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM25.example.net","FAHS92FA","1/27/2016 9:15 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM26.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/9/2016 10:53 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM27.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/9/2016 6:35 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM28.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/11/2016 12:21 PM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM29.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/9/2016 6:35 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM30.example.net","FAHS92FA","12/17/2015 7:06 AM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM31.example.net","FAHS92FA","2/11/2016 3:11 PM"
"ExampleDomain","VNAVWEM32.example.net","FAHS92FA","1/20/2016 2:31 PM"
```

Output Result = `LastLogon = 2/11/2016 3:11 PM`

Expected Output Result = `LastLogon = 2/12/2016 8:35 AM`

Anyone have any idea why it is not pulling the latest value?

Comment: `$userInfo.LastLogon` would be a string from the import and therefore not using datetime comparisons but string ones. `[datetime]$userInfo.LastLogon -gt $csvInputWithLatestLogonUserLastPlaceholder.LastLogon`

Comment: Ah okay thanks. It seems if I just sort first and pull the last one using the cast [datetime] with sort-object, it is a bit cleaner.

Comment: True. Point of it all is the object type.